# iPhone socket stream content conversion problem from bytes to arabic

Tags: iphone, sockets, iostream

I need to read an XML from socket which is having mixed content of arabic and english. my problem is that when I am converting the received bytes in UTF-8, I am getting the english content properly but arabic content is seems junk.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
rohit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright expert,

I got the solution to my problem :)

The problem relies on the desktop server part.

Actually I was passing the Arabic String from my desktop Java application using `DataOutputStream` with method `writeUTF()` which is actually sending the the header containing the length of the data using `writeShort()` implicitly. So on the iPhone part, when I was using
 `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;`

which is creating problem.

when I started to send data by `write(byte[])` it worked!

Comment: hi rohit, I have same issue. In server side we are using c#, I am getting arabic characters like ????? Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891510/arabic-characters-issue