# Arabic characters issue

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, unicode

I have some problems with displaying some Arabic text in my iPhone application. When I am displaying it on a `UILabel`, it shows like `?????? ????? ??????` The string comes from server as XML, I parse it and display on a UILabel. I dont know this is due to a problem in iPhone or from Server side.

- I want to know how can I determine the string coming from server is having correct encoding and is a valid Arabic characters.
- Is it suffice to print value each character and check it lies between Arabic Unicode characters. (Like ASCII value of character A is 65 and that of Z is 90. So a value 70 must be a ASCII character).
- In server the string is encoded with UTF8 encoding. And server program written in c#. What is the write encoding method to transfer Arabic text from server to iPhone?
- Do I need to use other fonts to display Arabic characters correctly.
- Is there any XML file with Arabic content in Internet, from where I can parse and display arabic text correctly?

Thanks in advance..

**EDIT:**

When I NSLogged XML data I got same `???? ???? ???` characters.

**EDIT**

See a XML styled data that I got in console.

```
<CB_SEC_COMP>
<SC_COMP_ID>9999</SC_COMP_ID>
<SCA_LONG_NAME>???? ????? ?????????? ????? ?????????</SCA_LONG_NAME>
<SCE_LONG_NAME>CHINA SECURITY &amp; SURVEILLANCE TECHNOLOGY, INC.</SCE_LONG_NAME>
<SCA_SHORT_NAME>???? ????? ?????????</SCA_SHORT_NAME>
<SCE_SHORT_NAME>CHINA SECURITY &amp; SUR</SCE_SHORT_NAME>
<SC_MRK_CODE>9</SC_MRK_CODE>
<SC_SEC_CODE>86</SC_SEC_CODE>
<SC_STATUS>Y</SC_STATUS>
<TICKER_ID>CSR</TICKER_ID>
<SC_MRK_TYPE_CODE>0001</SC_MRK_TYPE_CODE>
<SC_EXCHANGE>DFM</SC_EXCHANGE>
<CUR_CODE>AED</CUR_CODE>
</CB_SEC_COMP>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and debugging your code to see what value it has in the XML string before you parse it, after you parse it and before you add it to the UILabel? What research have you done to determine what characters can be passed in the XML and in what encoding?

Comment: Can you show your iOS code where you process the response from the server? It sounds like it might be an encoding issue on the client side (since you verified that your server is encoding in UTF8)

Comment: I am not sure that the xml was encoded in UTF8, it dont have header like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> . It just have some tags, and values for each tag. I ll send some part of XML when I print that into console. <COMP_SEC>0002</COMP_SEC>
    <SEC_DESC_A>???? ???? ??????</SEC_DESC_A>
    <SEC_DESC_E>Real Estate Index</SEC_DESC_E>
    <NET_PROFIT>0</NET_PROFIT>
    <NO_OF_FULLY_PAIDUP_SHARES>90000000</NO_OF_FULLY_PAIDUP_SHARES>
    <SCA_SHORT_NAME>????? ??????? ??????</SCA_SHORT_NAME>
    <SCE_SHORT_NAME>COMPANY NAME</SCE_SHORT_NAME>

Comment: SEC_DESC_A is arabic, and SEC_DESC_E is English values. SCA_SHORT_NAME arabic name. You can see some ??? characters there.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show how you get this xml(maybe url)

Comment: If you visit the URL that you are getting this XML from in a browser, what does it show up as?

Comment: I dont have a URL. We are doing it via sockets http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/ , from iPhone we send request via socket. the socket is bound to an IP address(Server IP address). Then we read socket for receiving data. The above XML snippet is a sample when I read data from socket.

Comment: @rakeshNS: Are you able to publish an example of this XML file anywhere? (Is it a public API we could fetch from?) That would help to work out if it's a server or client-side issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all answers. The problem was not with iPhone side. In server the XML was not correctly encoded to UTF8 string. When it correctly encoded I got valid arabic character. I only did code like

```
  NSString* lableText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:serverSentData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
```

for converting NSData to NSString and it worked well!!!

Answer (score 4):

You should sent to and receive text from server both in UTF-8 !!

From NSString.h:

```
enum {
    NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,      /* 0..127 only */
    ...

    **NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4,**
    ...

    **NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,**      /* An alias for NSUnicodeStringEncoding */  
    ....
};
typedef NSUInteger NSStringEncoding;
```

In your iOS app code should look like following: ((NSData*)serverSentData - nsdata representation of string recieved from server)

```
NSString* lableText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:serverSentData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
```

if it's UTF-16:

```
NSString* lableText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:serverSentData encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding ];
```

By the way, you can use json. It worked for me fine when I was sending cyrylic text.

Answer (score 0):

If your server sends the encoding in the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

then the built-in or any other well-written XML parser will handle and decode the PCDATA (the text between tags) in the correct way. If your server does not send this info and you can't change it on server side, then you have to guess yourself which encoding the server is using and convert the result manually to UTF-8. For example if your string is in pure 16 bit Unicode you can do it this way:

```
NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] autorelease];
NSData* convertedData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I am not getting header like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>. This is because, in server side the use a method DataSet.GetXML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxml(v=vs.71).aspx , which by default does not put <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>. Any way let me check the way you have converted string to data. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

This post may help:

[encode arabic letter unichar to regular letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700914/encode-arabic-letter-unichar-to-regular-letters)